# How to set the port number for the client in udp (client ,server) program in java?

Tags: java, sockets, network-programming, udp, serversocket

Each time I am running the client the server tells me a different port number. I searched on that and found that when I set the port to zero it looks for an available port, but I changed it to the number I want  `public static final int MYPORT = 5555;` and still getting a new port number each time from the server.

This is the print method:

```
System.out.printf(" using port %d\n", receivePacket.getPort());

DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket(null);
SocketAddress localBindPoint = new InetSocketAddress(MYPORT); socket.bind(localBindPoint); 
SocketAddress remoteBindPoint = new InetSocketAddress(args[0], Integer.valueOf(args[1]));
```

Comment: try to post (and indent) a more relevant part of your code.

Comment: add it in your post, not in the comments :)

Comment: It's been edited, do you know the answer?

Comment: I have added a sample of code that explains how to listen on port `5555`. What you have: Mac, Linux, Windows ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you missed the point, this piece of code listen on port 5555:

The istruction `packet.getPort()` in the following code returns the port number on the remote host to which this datagram is being sent or from which the datagram was received.

```
  int MYPORT = 5555;
  DatagramSocket dsocket = new DatagramSocket(MYPORT);
  byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];

  // Create a packet to receive data into the buffer
  DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);

  while (true) {
    // Wait to receive a datagram
    dsocket.receive(packet);

    // Convert the contents to a string, and display them
    String msg = new String(buffer, 0, packet.getLength());
    System.out.println(packet.getAddress().getHostName() + ": "
        + msg);

    // Reset the length of the packet before reusing it.
    packet.setLength(buffer.length);

    System.out.printf(" using port %d\n", packet.getPort());
  }
```

I have double checked locally:

```
sudo lsof -iUDP -n -P   | grep 5555
java      1606        freedev    5u  IPv6 0x9ed7290ce134656f      0t0  UDP *:5555
```